# Optimal approach for replacing the 8 header images in a child theme?

Tags: child-theme, theme-twenty-eleven, header-image

After creating a child theme which is made of `style.css` only (base on `twentyeleven`), the time has come to replace the images.

I found [this great tip](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/24527/12658) for accomplishing this by hacking the functions in `twentyeleven` but my main concern is minimizing work after a WordPress update.

I thought of simply replacing the images in `/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/headers` (while keeping the original names as came with `twentyeleven`) but is this better?

It looks like either way I will have re-apply my customizations after updating WordPress in the future.

Is there a way to replace the 8 images, *for a child theme*, and still maintain the changes after an update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am never sure about 'optimal approach' - however, I am using this in the functions.php in a child theme of Twenty Eleven

```
//deregister the header images of Twenty Eleven, and register a few new RAW header images//
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'raw_theme_header_images', 11 ); 

function raw_theme_header_images() {
unregister_default_headers( array( 'wheel', 'shore', 'trolley', 'pine-cone', 'chessboard', 'lanterns', 'willow', 'hanoi' ) ); 
$folder = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
register_default_headers( array(
    'coleslaw' => array(
        'url' => $folder.'/images/headers/coleslaw.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => $folder.'/images/headers/coleslaw-thumb.jpg',
        /* translators: header image description */
        'description' => __( 'Coleslaw', 'twentyeleven' )
    ),
    'tomato_and_sprouts' => array(
        'url' => $folder.'/images/headers/tomato_and_sprouts.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => $folder.'/images/headers/tomato_and_sprouts-thumb.jpg',
        /* translators: header image description */
        'description' => __( 'Tomato and Sprouts', 'twentyeleven' )
    )
)
);
}
```

the new images are in an /images folder in the child theme.

Comment: +1. Using [`unregister_default_headers()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_default_headers) is absolutely the correct approach.

Comment: @Michael Thanks +1. This looks similar to the solution in the link. Do I understand correctly from your answer that this solution doesn't modify any php file in the original `twentyeleven` and the above goes is only new code that goes into the child's directory?

Comment: correct - this all happens in the child theme's functions.php.

Comment: I'm worried about possible future additions to the images with an upgrade => the list of files are hardcoded so still 'vulnerable' in case of an update. Another options might be to empty `$_wp_default_headers`. You could opt for mapping that array with the `unregister_default_headers` function for future extra code in that function. Any thoughts on that?